# Verify output of xset

Tags: bash

`

```
#!/bin/bash
foo=$(cat /sys/class/leds/input3::numlock/brightness)
if $foo=1 
then
    notify-send 'Keyboard alert' 'Numlock Off.' --icon=dialog-information
else
    notify-send 'Keyboard alert' 'Numlock On.' --icon=dialog-information
fi
exit 0
```

`

So many variations of if var I'm exhausted.

Comment: `if $foo=1` should be `if [ "$foo" = 1 ]`. Please read a tutorial on shell scripting to learn proper syntax of `if` statements.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: And where is the `xset` ?